# How to create the same form in Group and Permission on Django Templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How can i custom my django templates like admin group page,
I tried to fetch all fields but its only fetch the avaible permissions and not fetching out chosen permission field
Please help me, Thanks

The fields i want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mteX0.png)

And then the results i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn4lg.png)

Some code in Forms:

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

Some code in Views:

```
def save_all(request, form, template_name):
    data = dict()
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            data['action'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
            error = form.errors

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserGroupForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = UserGroupForm()
        form2 = UserPermissionForm()
    return save_all(request, form, 'usergroups/create.html')
```

Some code in Templates:

```
<form action="" method="post" data-url="{% url 'userroles:create' %}" class="create-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Create Test</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">
            {% for field, error in error.items %}
                {{ error | striptags }}
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Some code in Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var ShowForm = function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr('data-url'),
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#modal-test').modal('show')
                django.jQuery('select.selectfilter, select.selectfilterstacked').each(function () {
                    var $el = $(this),
                        data = $el.data();
                    SelectFilter.init($el.attr('id'), data.fieldName, parseInt(data.isStacked, 10));
                });
            },
            success: function(data){
                django.jQuery('select.selectfilter, select.selectfilterstacked').each(function () {
                    var $el = $(this),
                        data = $el.data();
                    SelectFilter.init($el.attr('id'), data.fieldName, parseInt(data.isStacked, 10));
                });
                $('#modal-test .modal-content').html(data.html_form);
            }
        })
    };

    var SaveForm = function(){
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('data-url'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.form_is_valid){
                    if(data.deleteData){
                        Swal.fire({
                            type: 'warning',
                            title: 'Your Data is Deleted',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500
                        }).then(function(){
                            window.location.href = ''
                        })
                    } else if(data.action) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            type: 'success',
                            title: 'Your action is success',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500
                        }).then(function(){
                            window.location.href = ''
                        })
                    }

                    $('#modal-test').modal('hide');
                    console.log('Yes')
                } else {
                    $('#modal-test .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
                    console.log('Not')
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    }

    //create
    $('.show-form').click(ShowForm);
    $('#modal-test').on('submit', '.create-form', SaveForm);

    //update
    $(document).on('click', '.show-form-update', ShowForm);
    $('#modal-test').on('submit', '.update-form', SaveForm);

    //delete
    $(document).on('click', '.show-form-delete', ShowForm);
    $('#modal-test').on('submit', '.delete-form', SaveForm);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Django admin uses [filter_horizontal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) to show permissions. For you to adapt it, you have to use `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget.

forms.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple


class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'permissions': FilteredSelectMultiple("Permission", False, attrs={'rows':'2'}),
        }
```

and add widget scripts/styles to your frontend (I just copy-pasted all scripts and styles from admin page for django 2.2, so some of the probably not required):

create.html

```html
<form action="" method="post" data-url="" class="create-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Create Test</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert">
            {% for field, error in error.items %}
                {{ error | striptags }}
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{form}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/urlify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js"></script>
```

If you are using AJAX to fetch html form, add those styles and scripts to your main HTML page. After successful ajax call, call following javascript. That code is taken from `SelectFilter2.js`.

```
django.jQuery('select.selectfilter, select.selectfilterstacked').each(function () {
            var $el = $(this),
                data = $el.data();
            SelectFilter.init($el.attr('id'), data.fieldName, parseInt(data.isStacked, 10));
        });
```

Comment: but the choosen permissions is still not showing dude

Comment: also this form is only for creating new group. It will be empty by default when you run it. If you need to modify existing group, you have to provide that group to form, so it will query that form permissions.

Comment: its not show like in admin dude, it still same,just style was changed

Comment: By the way im using Django 1.11

Comment: Are you using ajax? If so, it is probably not executing javascript when loading it dynamically. Also for django 1.11 you'll need to go to your django admin and fetch actual scripts and styles - mine might not be correct for your version.

Comment: I've updated answer for ajax. Didn't really checked it with ajax, but that should work.

Comment: We can use [stackoverflow chats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to chat, but apart from that I'm not going to touch your code - you have to do it yourself. You can update your question with how your page calls for that form - it's probably uses `jquery` and something similar to `$.ajax({...})`